# How to send push notification to the user if he comes in a specific zone in Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services

I am working on an App in which i have to send a push notification to the user if he comes in a specific zone in Google Map, Now we doing this by calculating Distance b/w zone center and user but i don't think this is right way.
there is any other API provide by Google

Comment: LocationManager has proximity function and GoogleLocationServices also have function for geo-fencing. If you choose to perform geo-fencing at client side then there would be no point of gcm. Notifications can be produced locally using pre-fecthed data!

Comment: You can do it with geofencing.

Comment: Use the `Geofencing`. For more details please refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) and [here](https://github.com/udacity/google-play-services/tree/master/LocationLessons_Final/LocationLesson3_1/app/src/main/java/com/google/devplat/lmoroney/locationlesson3_1) is a sample code.